# Dividing an amount based on portions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing a GCSE maths past paper. The question is

> Three lads share £54 in total: John gets double the amount that Peter gets, and Tony gets double that of John. How much does each of them get?

How I thought I could solve this was by using algebra: 
$$ 2j+4t+p=54$$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: okay, sorry new to this thing

Comment: Instead of using different variables, use the same so you can actually solve the equation. Indeed, let $t$ be the amount of money that Peter gets. Then John gets double that amount, which is $2t$ and Tony gets double that, which is $4t$. Then you have $t+2t+4t=54$. Can you solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do better to do one equation at a time, and write them down as they are given. So $$J+P+T=54$$is the first thing you are told.

Then you have $$J=2P$$ and then $$T=2J$$

Your target should be to use the information in the last two equations to turn the first into an equation involving just one letter.

What you have tried to do is to put all the information you are told into one equation right away - but what you've come up with won't help you much and will probably confuse you. Keep it simple and do simple steps.

Comment: Okay thank you for this answer. It makes a lot of sense!

Comment: As a general comment, what you wrote: 2j+ 4t+ p= 54 is MEANINGLESS until you say what "t", "j", and "p" mean.  And, I think that if you do that you will see that this equation is incorrect.  I suspect that you mean "j" to mean the amount of money John got.  But if "John got twice as much as peter" then there is no reason to double the amount John receive.  Instead you should have written "Let t be the amount of money John receives, t the amount Tony receives, and p the amount peter receives.